# rbenv gives me to long error report in shell when something happens with my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell, rbenv

rbenv gives me to long error report in shell when something happens with my rails app in development. I don't need this. How can I disable it?

Example:

```
Exiting
/home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters
/connection_specification.rb:177:in `rescue in spec': Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord). (Gem::LoadError)
    from /home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:174:in `spec'
    from /home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
    from /home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:120:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
    from /home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:28:in `block in on_load'
    from /home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `each'
    from /home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `on_load'
    from /home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:116:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from /home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from /home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
    from /home/kirill/Projects/kirill-zhuravlov-blog/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /home/kirill/Projects/kirill-zhuravlov-blog/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /home/kirill/Projects/kirill-zhuravlov-blog/config.ru:in `new'
    from /home/kirill/Projects/kirill-zhuravlov-blog/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
    from /home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
    from /home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
    from /home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in `log_to_stdout'
    from /home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'
    from /home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
    from /home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /home/kirill/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

But the actual problem is just my commented " #gem 'pg' " in gemfile. Im using latest LTS Ubuntu, ruby 2.3 and rails 4.2

Comment: Is it so critical for your?) In ideal case you would never see it again.

Comment: Why did you commented out the pg gem? Did you add another database connector instead?

Comment: The problem is not error itself but the long output. The issue is that it happens all the time when eny error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution to this issue. I open bashrc(shell startup configuration file) in terminal

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

and cut

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
```

then I save changes and exit (ctrl+O enter ctrl+X).
And the long output is gone.